react-native-qrcode-scanner not working on IOS
I implemented react-native-qrcode-scanner working fine on Android. but problem on iOS.
"react-native": "0.73.6",
"react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
"react-native-permissions": "^4.1.5",
my podFile is
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"

also I tried
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"

but getting errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/ORMFf318.png)
please give me the solution to how I can react-native-qrcode-scanner on IOS.

Have you installed react-native-permissions library and performed native setup for that in iOS? if not please do that and try, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions

Also do not forgot to do pod install after podfile changes.

@JatinBhuva I performed native setup for iOS and also pod install but getting same error. which I mentioned below.

Do you have this in your Podfile ? with rn >=0.72 the setup is different.
def node_require(script)
  # Resolve script with node to allow for hoisting
  require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
    "require.resolve(
      '#{script}',
      {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
    )", __dir__]).strip
end

node_require('react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb')
node_require('react-native-permissions/scripts/setup.rb')

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

setup_permissions([
  'Camera',
])


Now react-native-qrcode-scanner is working
